# az keyvault certificate import fails with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_notBefore'

Tags: openssl, keytool, azure-keyvault, pkcs#12

Trying to import a certificate converted from jks format to pfx, but I get the following error:

```
az keyvault certificate import --name truststore-pfx --vault-name mykeyvault --file truststore.pfx --password *******
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_notBefore'
```

Both keytool -list and openssl pkcs12 -info correctly shows the cert.

Importing fails also via the portal. Any idea how to get it imported?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it looks like it has no notBefore field, which is a critical requirement. Take a look at the cert; if you're on Windows use certutil:

certutil -dump

or, on Linux/Mac, you can use OpenSSL:

openssl x509 -inform der -in  -noout -text

And double-check there is a NotBefore field.

If you're not 100% sure, go ahead and dump the output here and I can take a look!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I think this problem is only because of the lack of private key in the pfx file. The Azure documentation suggests the same: 
"When you are importing the certificate, you need to ensure that the key is included in the file itself."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/certificate-scenarios

So one cannot use azure keyvault certificates feature to store/distribute a CA certificate only.